# How to overwrite a file in C?

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to overwrite the contents of a FILE in C. Currently I have:

```
FILE* file  = fopen("filename.txt",  "r+");
fprintf(file, "%d", 1); // regardless of what's in the file, i want to clear it and put 1 in there
...
// legacy code somewhere else in the code base. can't change.
rewind(file);
fprintf(file, "%d", 2);
fflush(file);
```

However, this will not work properly. The result will be:

1, 21

Each subsequent number will be written to the beginning of the 1. For example:

1, 21, 31, 41, ...

I would like to know if there is a way to always overwrite what's in the file so the following is produced:

1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I have changed the code to:

```
FILE* file  = fopen("filename.txt",  "w+");
```

The problem still persists.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You decide that in `fopen`. Just use `"w"` or `"w+"` instead of `"r+"`.

Comment: Hi Bo, sorry you're suggestion isn't working :( Perhaps I am not doing something right?

Comment: Maybe I just solved your first problem - how to clear the old file. If the other code does a rewind, we cannot really stop that.

Comment: so if the other code does not do a rewind then the problem can be fixed?

Comment: Also, if i have fscanf in after my first write of "1", would that cause problems?

Comment: Yes. :-) When switching between reading and writing you *have to* use `fseek` to position the next operation (or possibly rewind to start all over).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, you can't overwrite anything with fprintf. You have to use fwrite, e.g. something like

```
rewind(file);
char buf[10];
sprintf(buf, "%d", 2);
fwrite(buf, strlen(buf), 1, file);
```

From your code and question I don't quite follow what it is you actually try to do, but hope this helps (half a year after you asked).

Comment: fprintf can most definitely overwrite things in r+ mode.

Answer (score 2):

use following command before `fprintf`:

```
freopen(NULL,"w+",file);
```

Answer (score -1):

I was going through the same problem. I wanted to overwrite the same file from what I was taking the input. So after trying different methods, I decided to create another pointer that points to the same file. So I have one pointer which reads the input and then I close that using fclose() and I have another pointer for overwriting the same file and again I close that using fclose(). That worked for me.